# onchange function not working

Tags: javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function urlchange() {
   var val = document.getElementById('fix');
   e = val.options[val.selectedIndex].value;
   window.open('e','mywindow','width=500,height=500')
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<select id="fix" onblur="urlchange()">
   <option selected="selected">select</option>
   <option value="http://www.airtel.in">airtel</option>
   <option value="http://google.in">google</option>
</select>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Any description of the problem? The desired and the actual result?

Answer (score 2):

You have write this code to fire when it's blurred....!!!
If You want onchange then try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function urlchange() {

var val= document.getElementById('fix');

e=val.options[val.selectedIndex].value;




window.open(e,'mywindow','width=500,height=500')

}



</script>



<select id="fix" onchange="urlchange()">
<option selected="selected">select</option>

<option value="http://www.airtel.in">airtel</option>
<option value="http://google.in">google</option>

</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't put quotes around the variable.

```
window.open(e,'mywindow','width=500,height=500')
```

If you do it will try to navigate the new window to 'e' instead of the url in the html.

http://jsfiddle.net/9cMRq/

Comment: thanks for reply, i tried this also but it is still not working

Comment: it is here http://jsfiddle.net/9cMRq/ maby your doing something else wrong outside the code than?

Comment: thanks i made a stupid mistake i call this function on onblur now i change it, your post is also usefull for me